# Автоматическое согласие или предотвращение показа всплывающего окна (Wordpress ACF form)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, всплывающее-окно, acf, reload

Есть страница с формой. При выборе одного с параметров select нужно обновлять страницу с добавлением GET параметра в URL. Я добавляю через смену document.location.search, после чего идет автоматическая перезагрузка страницы, но перед этим появляется диалоговое окно браузера: [image: окно]

Подскажите как избежать необходимости подтверждать перезагрузку страницы или вообще появления данного окна. Я уже пытался сбрасывать значения формы в целом и данного поля в частности, но не помогло.

Comment: Автоматически такое окно появляться не будет. Приведите пример кода и используемые фреймворки.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Форма генерируется WP плагином ACF, при  помощи функции acf_form. Пока поле селект(для выбора записи студента, это кастомный тип записей) остается без изменений, страница перезагружается без проблем. Насколько я понял они используют Select2 для работы с полями.

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос. А также можете добавить метки. Это поможет найти человека, который спец в WP. Я не спец по WP.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Спасибо за помощь!